# Get Windows- Non-Drive MyDocuments Folder

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Accessing the "MyDocuments" folder in C# is easy with `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` which returns the path:
`C:\Users\userName\Documents\`

But if the user has OneDrive active, the method above brings me to the path:
`C:\Users\userName\OneDrive\Documents`

**How can I access the normal myDocuments folder if the user has OneDrive active?**

I could simply remove that part from the directory path manually, but I would prefer are more "clean" solution.

Comment: From the users perspective their documents folder (the link in explorer, all other applications that save to the documents folder) becomes the one in the one-drive folder. Are you sure you want your application to specifically not follow this pattern?

Comment: Also it is not always `C:\Users\<username>\Documents` (although it generally is). for example, corporate users may have this changed by their IT departments for various reasons (e.g. a shared documents folder for a sales teams desktop systems...)

Are you sure your app always wants to use that folder (which may not even exist)?

Comment: I agree with @MHornbacher, it seems like `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` is working as intended as MyDocuments is personal to each user on the OS. If you want, maybe you could see if `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` acts differently but I suspect it will return the same directory as they're equivalent to each other.

Comment: In the case you just need to store data, use the AppData folders instead of Documents.

Comment: @MHornbacher Thank you for that information. I did not know, that it is common to change that. 

Our application stores Excel-Documents there and uses it as templates. The thing is, that excel behaves weird if the files are saved in the AppData folder because it uses this directory for their temporary unsaved files. It seems that I'm not able to find the original link for that anymore...

Comment: Also - yes I want to not save it there, since OneDrive accesses the file to synch it and my application cannot access it. "File is in use by another Process".